# All simple paths for graph in R

Tags: r, igraph, bioconductor

Using igraph, I am trying to calculate all_simple_paths for a dense network that has 851 nodes and 3,135 edges, but it crashes. memory.limit() is set to be 8 GBs. Any idea how I can get around this issue? Does Bioconductor have a similar algorithm that might be faster?

Comment: Buy more memory?

Comment: @GaborCsardi if only :)